# Facebook PHP sdk login url using AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook-graph-api

I've created a facebook app that uses the facebook php sdk (version 3.0) for authorization and to access the facebook graph api.

I would like to load the oauth dialog (BaseFacebook::getLoginUrl()) asynchronously as an iframe in a lightbox style modal ([colorbox](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)). For some reason when the url loads, it only displays the facebook logo and a link that says "Go to Facebook.com".

Does anybody know why this doesn't work?

Here is a demo of what is happening: http://andrew.23.newco.bluhq.us/proto/oauth2Proto/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/):

> Because of the way that we currently load iframes for Apps on
>   Facebook.com, it is important that you navigate the top window of the
>   user's browser to the OAuth Dialog.

Using the OAuth dialog in an iFrame is NOT the top window!

Comment: I wasn't sure if that applied only to canvas apps since it is only mentioned in the canvas documentation and nowhere in the authentication or graph api sections of the documentation.